# Images flowing out of a tablet layout inside a constraint layout

Tags: android, layout

I'm facing troubles with a TableLayout here. My goal would be to make two columns with equal width, each one with one image that should adjust it's width so it fits inside the cell's available space, but it seems the images keep overflowing outside the available space in the cell/row. I have tested some properties without luck so far, so I could use some help here.

This is the current outcome in the design view:

[image: Images flowing out limits]

I'd have expected the teddy bear to occupy only 50% of the row width at the left, and then the other image (which is an umbrella) to fit into the remaining 50% at the right of the bear. But you see that's not what's happening.

This is the layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.DebugFragment">


    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableImages"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/teddy_bear" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/umbrella" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**UPDATE**: Following Jakob F advice of replacing stretchColumns with shrinkColumns solves the issue with the image overflowing the layout boundaries, but breaks the requirement of both columns being of same width. See image:

[image: Different column width]

**UPDATE**: Keeping the stretchColumns="*" and setting the layout_width of each image to 0dp does the trick of keeping them inside the layout boundaries AND make both columns the same with. Now I just have to figure out how to keep them at the same height, but that's a different issue I think.

[image: Same column width]

**UPDATE**: Adding android:scaleType="fitStart" to both images aligns both of them to the top as desired, but it keeps adding space under the images for no reason (I have changed the background color so the limits of the images are more obvious).

[image: Extra space being added under images]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I managed to solve all the issues by myself. Can't help but complain on how difficult such an obvious task can become sometimes in Android. I had to go over a lot of trial and error with a number of different attributes which functionality seem anything but obvious in most cases. Anyway, this is the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#99ffff"
    tools:context=".view.DebugFragment">


    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableImages"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="16dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/teddy_bear" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="16dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/umbrella" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result:
[image: Final outcome]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `android:shrinkColumns="*"` instead of `android:strechColumns="*"` to make all columns shrinkable, so that the width is automatically determined to fit the images on screen. Stretching them would only enable them to become larger.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, Jakob. That solves the images flowing out but then the columns are not the same size anymore neither.